# Variance of a mixed variable

Tags: probability, variance

I am studying probability on my own and couldn't find anything on this in my textbooks.
Say we have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, with known means $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$, and known variances $\sigma^{2}_{1}$ and $\sigma^{2}_{2}$. 
$A$ is defined to be a linear combination of both variables. How can you interpret the variance of $A$? And how can you calculate $\textbf{E}(A^{2})$ in order to find such variance?

Does this generalize to more complex functions $A(X,Y)$?

Comment: Concerning the calculation of the variance of a sum of random variables, search for "Bienaymé formula". Concerning the interpretation: What exactly are you thinking of? Do you have a general understanding of what the variance of a random variable is? Why should it be different for a sum? Concerning generelizations: Any formula you know for $E(f(X))$ (e.g. if you know a density) can be applied to calculate the variance. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: But in general, you cannot expect to calculate the variance of $X+Y$ just from the variances of $X$ and $Y$. If for example $X=Y$, we have $Var(X+Y)=4Var(X)$, but if they have the same distribution but are independent, we have $Var(X+Y)=2Var(X)$

Comment: I guess I was not paying attention to the role of independence in how the sum might vary. Taking independence into account, I think I now see how the meaning of a variance of a sum not that different. Can you direct me to a link to learn more about expectations of functions of random variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the data provided and the properties of variance, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Var}(A) = \textbf{Var}(aX+bY) = a^{2}\textbf{Var}(X) + b^{2}\textbf{Var}(Y) = a^{2}\sigma^{2}_{1} + b^{2}\sigma^{2}_{2}
\end{align*}

Once $X$ and $Y$ are independent, they are uncorrelated, which means that $\textbf{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$ and, consequently, the formula above is correct.

As you may have noticed, we did not need to use the value $\textbf{E}(A^{2})$ directly in order to obtain the variance: it is enough to make use of the variance properties.

As to the general case, the strategy to solve the problem depends on the expression of $A(X,Y)$.

Comment: I see how the general case might vary. As for (^2), in general, would you just expand the square of A and then see if you get something you can work with?

Comment: In accordance to the given information, a good start point would be to notice that

$$\textbf{Var}(A) = \textbf{E}(A^{2}) - \textbf{E}(A)^{2}$$

Once we know the value of $\textbf{Var}(A)$ and $\textbf{E}(A)$ can be easily calculated,  you obtain the value of $\textbf{E}(A^{2})$. More precisely, we have

$$\textbf{E}(A) = \textbf{E}(aX+bY) = a\textbf{E}(X) + b\textbf{E}(Y) = a\mu_{1} + b\mu_{2}$$